# New record and many to many insert

Tags: mysql, transactions, eloquent, many-to-many, lumen

I am working in a project where the users have a rate plan associated. When a new user is created, a valid rate plan must be specified.

I have the following MySQL schema and Eloquent models:

[image]

```
/**
 * User Eloquent model file ...
 *
 */

public function ratePlans() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
      'App\Models\RatePlan',
      'users_rate_plans',
      'users_id', 
      'rate_plans_id'
   );
}
```

So, to create a new user with your selected rate plan i do:

```
try {
   \DB::beginTransaction();
   $model->create($data);
   $model->ratePlans()->attach($data['rate_plan'], ['active' => 1]);
   \DB::commit();
   return $model;
} catch(\Exception $e) {
   \DB::rollback();
   return false;
}
```

But, i am getting the next exception:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'users_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users_rate_plans`
>   (`active`, `rate_plans_id`, `users_id`) values (1, 43, ))

Why te transaction didn't work ? How i can do that task ?

**UPDATE 1**

I changed the transaction code but, the result is the same.

```
try {
   \DB::beginTransaction();
   $ratePlan = \App\Models\RatePlan::find($data['rate_plan']);
   $user->ratePlans()->attach($ratePlan, ['active' => 1]);
   $user->create($data);
   \DB::commit();
   return $user;
} catch(\Exception $e) {
   \DB::rollback();
   die($e->getMessage());
   return false;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I changed the transaction code again and its works:

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
$user = \App\Models\User::create($data);
$ratePlan = \App\Models\RatePlan::find($data['rate_plan']);
$user->ratePlans()->attach($ratePlan, ['active' => 1]);            \DB::commit();
return $user;
```

Comment: I think you need to select the Id of the created user and attach it to the function.

Comment: @Nikolaus is a transaction, i don't know the created user id. Anyway, according to [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not loading the rate_plans entity.

```
$model->ratePlans()->attach($data['rate_plan'], ['active' => 1]);
```

In this line `$data['rate_plan']` shoud be an instance of your model "rate_plans", and I'm assuming that `$model` in this situation stand for an entity of your `User` model

Also have tried a test without the transaction if the result's is the same ?
I give you an example of one of my code which is similar:

```
try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $group = Group::create($data);
        $employees = User::whereIn('reference', $references)->get();
        $group->employees()->attach($employees);
        $group->save();
        DB::commit();
} catch(Exception $e) { [...] }
```

Good luck